# preg_replace to remove invalid character (allow utf-8)

Tags: php, regex

I use the following function to clean-up my string before I use it on my export:

```
function cleanString($source) {
    $source = str_replace('&', 'and', $source);
    $source = preg_replace('~[^\p{L}\p{N}]++~u', ' ', $source);
    return trim($source);
}
```

This works fine, but I want to modify it to allow `,` (commas) and parenthesis `(` and `)`.

At the moment, this is what's happening:

`Name, Brand Name (Some & Slogan)` ==> `Name Brand Name Some and Slogan`

How can I update the above regex pattern to allow commas and parenthesis?

I tried the following: `$source = preg_replace('~[^\p{L}\p{N}]++~u\,\(\)', ' ', $source);` and I am getting the error: `Unknown modifier '\'`.

Any ideas?

Comment: In a character class you do not need to escape parenthesis.

Comment: @ZoltanMagyar parenthesis are not inside character class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include `(`, `)` and `,` in your negation character class:

```
$source = preg_replace('~[^\p{L}\p{N}(),]+~u', ' ', $source);
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eN9fG9/1)

Comment: Also there is no need to use `++` here.